# How to execute APP downloaded from Google Play in AOSP?

Tags: android, android-source

I succeed AOSP build in Nexus 4 and install google apps.

Also, I tried download app from google play and succeed install.

But, When I execute that app, failed execute.

So, check the Logcat I can find 'load .so failed' error in android run time.

Why doesn't working?

Please, how can I find solution this problem?

Comment: which app did u installed?

Comment: @random About bank app and mp3 player.

Comment: what @stefanTo asnwered is bit closer to answer... u basically need to find the what so files are missing and need to push inside /system/lib

Comment: Sorry, I just tag you...
I don't understand your answer.
Why need to push inside /system/lib?

Answer (score 0):

**The short answer is:** You probably can't fix this yourself.

The *.so files probably are native running libraries the developer of the app used in his code.

**One guess:**
Android 5 is capable of 64bit now. 
While the Java part of the code works automatically with 64bit, the so-files need to be prepared for it by the developer.

**Another guess:**
The new ART Runtime causes problems in JNI. For developers, see this: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/verifying-apps-art.html and

You should contact the developer and ask whether he checked his App on Android 5.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I build Android 4.3 AOSP in Nexus 4.
So, I think it's not problem about Android 5.
But, 'another guess' case is interesting.
I try this.
Thank you.